The application of zero-one law in probability theory
I try to apply martingale convergence and 0-1 law.
Suppose I have a bandit with 2 arms such that 2 arms have equal mean rewards. I initialize 2 parameters for each arm to calculate the policy, which then sample to choose an arm. After choosing the arm, I will receive a sampled reward, which will be used to update the parameter. Empirically, I observe that the probability will be either [1,0] or [0,1] after several updates. Theoretically, any policies (such as [0.7, 0.3]) will have the same return due to same mean rewards. I was trying to prove why my empirical performance looks like that and came across 0-1 law (Levy 0-1 law). However, I still didn't see how the law relates to my case.
I have been looking at Levy's zero-one law. Levy's 0-1 statement is If $\mathcal F_n \uparrow \mathcal F_\infty$ and $A \in\mathcal F_\infty$, then $\mathbb E[1_A|\mathcal F_n] =1_A$ a.s. However, I cannot make connections of the event A to my case.
Can anyone familiar with probability theory give me some suggestions? Thanks!
